# Starting DMA transaction from irq handler in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, dma

I am developing driver for beaglebone black like board. Driver communicate with FPGA. When FPGA has data to read it triggers an irq. So I have to quickly start DMA transaction to read data. Is it possible to start transaction from atomic context?

For now I send a task to high priority workqueue and it starts DMA transaction but sometimes, when I work on 30mb/s I got large delay (about 200-500 microseconds) between the call `queue_work` from irq handler and starting the job from workqueue.

So can I start DMA directly from irq or is there a faster way to start DMA transaction from irq handler?

I use linux kernel 4.9.

**UPDATED:**

```
void init(){
    g_fpga_dma_queue = alloc_workqueue("fpga_dma_queue", WQ_UNBOUND |Q_HIGHPRI, 1);
}

static irq_handler_t irqReadyRead(unsigned int irq, void* dev_id, struct pt_regs* regs)
{
    if(g_fpga_dma_queue) {
        queue_work(g_fpga_dma_queue, &fpga_dma_work);
    }

    return (irq_handler_t)IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static void dma_callback_read(void *param)
{
    struct dma_chan *chan = g_dma_chan_read;

    switch (dma_async_is_tx_complete(chan, cookie_read, NULL, NULL)) {
        case DMA_COMPLETE:
            irqraised1_read = 1;
            g_good_dma++;
            break;

        case DMA_ERROR:
            irqraised1_read = -1;
            g_bad_dma++;
            break;

        default:
            irqraised1_read = -1;
            g_bad_dma++;
            break;
    }

    
    complete(&dma_comp_read);
}

static int read_dma(int count)
{
    struct dma_device *dev;
    struct dma_async_tx_descriptor *tx;
    unsigned long flags;
    int result = 0;

    dev = g_dma_chan_read->device;
    flags = DMA_CTRL_ACK | DMA_PREP_INTERRUPT;

    tx = dev->device_prep_dma_memcpy(g_dma_chan_read, dmaphysbuf_read, (unsigned long) FPGA_READ_BUFFER_ADDR,
                                     (size_t) count, flags);

    if (!tx) {
        DBG_LOG("device_prep_dma_memcpy failed\n");

        return -ENODEV;
    }

    irqraised1_read = 0u;
    dma_comp_read.done = 0;

    /* set the callback and submit the transaction */
    tx->callback = dma_callback_read;
    tx->callback_param = NULL;
    cookie_read = dmaengine_submit(tx);
    dma_async_issue_pending(g_dma_chan_read);

    wait_for_completion(&dma_comp_read);

    /* Check the status of the completed transfer */

    if (irqraised1_read < 0) {
        DBG_LOG("edma copy: Event Miss Occured!!!\n");
        dmaengine_terminate_all(g_dma_chan_read);

        result = -EAGAIN;
    }
}
static void fpga_dma_work_handler(struct work_struct *w){
    size_t count = readSize();
    read_dma();
}
```

Sometimes (when we insert or remove usb flash, when any driver write messages in terminal ) I got very big delay between irq handler and when DMA actualy starts (~1 ms)

Comment: can you provide a code snippets of the key points of your solution?

Comment: I added a code snippets

Comment: Do you have any problems with ommiting workqueues and starting dma directly from irq handler?

Comment: Yes, some transactions end with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the main reason of delays. I got a huge delay in my driver when any driver prints something in console (when I insert usb, remove net cabel, call printk from driver, etc), usualy I got max delays between pushing task in a workqueue and starting dma transactions about 100-200 microseconds (~10-20 microseconds for preparing dma transaction) and it is ok for now.

And I found the reason why some dma transactions end with errors when I start them directly from irq handler, I get interupts every ~500 microseconds and if delay ocure after irq handler and before dma transaction actualy starts I start new transaction before previous one ends (dma transaction shoud be done very quckly about 10 microseconds and I dont check that previous transaction is finished and with singlethread workqueue it was imposible to start next task before previous one is complete so I forgot to check that transaction is finished when I change my code to start transactions from irq handler)

Now I continue using high priority queue with disabled kernel output to console. And  may be I try to use tasklet insted workqueue if I will need smaller delay for starting dma transaction (I think starting dma from irq is not good because it takes about 10-20 microseconds in irq handler on my board but maybe sometimes it is ok)